# MongoDB C# driver : use internal contructor is impossible?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, domain-driven-design

I would like to work with Domain Driven Design tactical patterns, using MongoDb as the storage engine of my aggregates.

To ensure object encapsulation, and lowering 'impedance mismatch' of my model to the infrastructure layer : I need to provide internal scoped constructor (for internal object creation in my Domain layer only from domain event), and provide public factories for extra domain layer object creation.

Example

```
// Aggregate
public class FlashInfo : AggregateRoot<FlashInfoId>
{
    public Information Text { get; private set; } // => see the problem with this VO
    public DateTime ActivationDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; private set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; private set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; private set; }

 // ...

}

   // Value Object
    public class Information : Value<Information>
    {
       public string Text { get; } 
       internal Information(string text)
        {
            Text = text;
        }        
 
        public static implicit operator string(Information info) => info.Text;
            
        public static Information CreateInformation(string text)
        {
            CheckValidity(text);
            return new Information(text);
        }
 
        private static void CheckValidity(string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                throw new InformationTextIsEmptyException("The information text must not be null or empty");            
 
if (text.Length > 100)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(text), "The information text cannot be longer that 100 characters");
        }
    }
```

Then on persisting my Aggregate with it's VO :

```
_mongoClient.GetDatabase("mydb").GetCollection<FlashInfo>("mycollection").InsertOneAsync(document);
```

When I use an **internal constructor** for my information VO it's set to an empty object in MongoDb
[image: Internal ctor lead to an empty VO in Mongo]

When I use a **public constructor** for my information VO instead, the object persisted is persisted as expected (with it's value)
[image: Public ctor works as expected]

MongoDB driver version and framework version

```
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.13.1" />
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advocate against this type of creational pattern. You can see "Don't Create Aggregate Roots" by Udi Dahan for some guidance on how to think about the creation of Aggregates (https://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/).

As an example, let's say you want to create a new Person.

1. You create a domain request, CreatePerson. It has the Id of the
   person to create.
2. Your domain service requests the Person with that
   Id from the repository. The repository reads from the database but
   doesn't find a record for that Id. It instead creates one and
   inserts it into the in-memory collection and returns it to the
   caller as if it were found.
3. The domain service updates the person's name and other information.
   The unit of work is committed and the person is created in the
   database.

In the above, at no point is a new Person instance explicitly created by the domain. Effectively, you would always do a get/read to access an instance of an Aggregate Root, even if it is a new one. In this way, your logic is simplified and you avoid the headache of creating internal constructors. As a bonus, you also get idempotency when creating instances of your Aggregate Root since the same request submitted twice will simply load the aggregate on the second request and update the information or raise an error if you prefer to fail when an attempt is made to create a Person twice.

Comment: Sure, but it's more relative to have an aggregate instanciating it's own ValueObject properties from a Domain Event see https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Domain-Driven-Design-with-.NET-Core/blob/master/Chapter11/in-database/Marketplace.Domain/UserProfile/UserProfile.cs. Mongo team replied me that internal/private ctor are not supported by the .net lib directy so a public ctor becomes more obvious then